# How to join files using 'tail' command while displaying limited lines

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tail

I have multiple log files and I want to display its joint output. One way of doing this is by executing this command:

```
tail file-1 file-2
```

But I also want to display only a specific number of lines and if I include the *number of lines* parameter in this command like this:

```
tail -n file-1 file-2
```

OR

```
tail -n file-1 -n file-2
```

It says `tail: option used in invalid context`

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *number of lines* to your tail command:

```
tail -n 10 file-1 -n 10 file-2
```

Comment: Slight rectification in your command: tail -n x-lines file-1 -n y-lines file-2

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell to repeat a command for each file -

> for each in file-1 file-2; do tail -X $each; done

Or, if the files are all of the same type

> find . -type f -name "namespec" -exec tail -X {} \;